Attention needed on comment of old question
I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this question, so excuse me in advance! 
How can I draw attention to my related question/comment on an old question asked by someone else? Can I simply flag it to draw moderaters attention?
Thanks! 

Meta is the place to ask for help with using the main page, or for discussing ideas for the site. So, don't worry, your question here is just right. :)

I'm not exactly sure what you are getting at with your question, but if you post a comment on a question, the author will be notified. If you want to notify someone else, you can write @username, after a few letters a selection box with users will pop up to allow you to select one.
If you post a link to another question in a post or comment, the linked question will show up in the right column in the "Linked" section, just how questions with similar topics show up in the "Related" section.
If there is a problem with the comment, please flag for moderator review.

I'm intending to ask a question as a comment but wasn't sure if I should post it as a separate question or not.

If it is only a request to specify a point already elaborated in the post, add a comment, otherwise ask a new question and include a link to the previous question.

It depends on what kind of attention you're trying to draw. If you're trying to draw moderator attention to it (e.g. because you want it deleted) then you should flag it as "other (needs diamond attention)"
If you're looking for an answer to a related question, you should ask a new question about only the part not covered by the previous question. You can optionally link to the old question for context. 
If you have the exact same question, you should add a bounty to the question (a privilege you will get at 75 reputation) to draw attention to the old question. 
You can also do some combination of these things (e.g. asking a new question and adding a bounty to the old one.)
Does that answer your question? 

I was actually trying to get everyone's attention. Eventually I'm thinking I should post a new question with a link to the related question.
